# How to store temporary data (like cookie) in Paw javascript extension

Tags: paw-app

I'm working on javascript based extension for Paw REST Client - OAuth2 authorization with grant_type:password.
So I send the username and password and receive access_token and refresh_token. Here I want to store somewhere the tokens (with ttl 60m) using only javascript (and this method must be allowed by Paw's engine).
Are there any ways to do this and which of them is best?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that for now, unfortunately! But I love the idea. I'll try to have such an API added in the next release or so...